# Can chunked Transfer-Encoded data include CRLF?

Tags: http

I've read about chunked Transfer-Encoding and basically got the point. However, there's something I don't quite understand and hasn't been reffered to in all the sources I've read.

A chunked encoded data is structured as a series of chunks, each structured as follows:

```
<chunk size> (In ASCII bytes expressing the hexadecimal value)
\r\n
<data>
\r\n
```

What I don't understand is: what if the payload itself contains a `\r\n` ? Doesn't it interfere with the way we track when a chunk starts and ends?
You could argue that even if it does, we still have the chunk size before the chunk so that CRLF shouldn't bother us, but then I would ask - if so, why having these CRLFs in the first place?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can include `\r\n`.

As to why this format was chosen: I don't know. Maybe to make it more readable when uses with textual data.

Comment: OK, so basically the right way to safely read this data is just verify that I got a `\r\n` after the number of bytes specified in the beggining of the chunk?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely should check for that. Note that in theory there can also be extension parameters after the chunk length; if you care about correctness you will have to skip over these.